# SQL syntax error in Java Servlet

Tags: java, sql, database, syntax

I tried to do this:

```
query1="INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `password`, `login`, `familiya`, `name`, `otchestvo`, `age`, `country`, `city`, `mob`, `skype`) VALUES ("+user.getEmail()+","+user.getPassword()+","+user.getLogin()+","+user.getFamiliya()+","+user.getName()+","+user.getOtchestvo()+",11,"+user.getCountry()+","+user.getCity()+","+user.getMob()+","+user.getSkype()+")";
```

what did I do wrong? All "get" is not null, only syntax error.

I want to post image of database but I need 10 reputation...
all fields are `varchar(15)`, age is `int(2)`

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@mail.ru,12345,dima,Dmitriev,dima,Dmitrievich,11,Dmitrountry,Dmitriegrad,2020327' at line 1
```

Comment: There are lot of issues with your SQL, for one, Varchar type should be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: are they all varchar?

Comment: Don't construct your sql like that. Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: Which database are you using? Looks like MySQL, but...?

Comment: You are also using reserved words like `password` for fields. I'll suggest to surround them by `[ ]`

Comment: not the whole values should be wrapped, check my answer below to see how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put single quotes " ' " around your string values (varchar, text etc)

so

```
String query1="INSERT INTO users(email, password, login, familiya, name, otchestvo, age, country, city, mob, skype) VALUES  ('"+user.getEmail()+"','"+user.getPassword()+"','"+user.getLogin()+"','"+user.getFamiliya()+"','"+user.getName()+"','"+user.getOtchestvo()+"',11,'"+user.getCountry()+"','"+user.getCity()+"','"+user.getMob()+"','"+user.getSkype()+"')";
```

not string related types DON't get single quotes....

A better way to do this however is using PreparedStatement,

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO users(email, password, login, familiya, name, otchestvo, age, country, city, mob, skype) VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

 try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
     preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getEmail);
     preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword);
     preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getLogin());
     preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getFamiliya());
     preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getName());
     preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getOtchestvo());
     preparedStatement.setInt(7, 11);
     preparedStatement.setString(8, user.getCountry());
     preparedStatement.setString(9, user.getCity());
     preparedStatement.setString(10, user.getMob());
     preparedStatement.setString(11, user.getSkype());
     preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: i need to import PreparedStatement from Java.Sql or jdbc ?

Comment: java.sql.PreparedStatement